# Alternativa ao uso de variaveis em views no mysql

Tags: mysql, query, view

preciso criar uma view que obtenha o percentual de cada produto em relação ao total de produtos, fiz a query abaixo e esta funcionando como um select normal:

```
set @total := (SELECT round(sum(gin.Caixa_9L /1000),4) FROM gin where sales_channel = 'duty paid' or sales_channel = 'travel retail');
set @duty_paid := (select round(sum(gin.Caixa_9L /1000),4) from gin where sales_channel = 'travel retail');
select round(((@duty_paid / @total)),1) * 100 as percentual;
```

Ocorre que preciso transformar isso numa view, mas o mysql não aceita variáveis em views. Como posso proceder? da pra fazer de outro jeito?

Consegui resolver assim:

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
PROCEDURE gin.`share duty paid`()
BEGIN
set @total := (SELECT round(sum(gin.Caixa_9L /1000),4) FROM gin where
sales_channel = 'duty paid' or sales_channel = 'travel retail');
set @duty_paid := (select round(sum(gin.Caixa_9L /1000),4) from gin where     
sales_channel = 'duty paid');
select round(((@duty_paid / @total)),1) * 100 as percentual;
END
```

Comment: Crie uma função e depois chame-a pela view. Ou ainda, você poderá criar uma **coluna computada** em sua tabela.

Comment: @ismael, consegui criando uma procedure, e dentro dela eu coloquei a minha query com as variáveis. Mesmo assim obrigado pelo help.

Comment: Se possível, coloque o código da sua solução na resposta, ela poderá servir para outras pessoas futuramente. Contribua com a comunidade ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é necessário usar variáveis, você pode fazer desta maneira:

```
SELECT 
round(((aux2.duty_paid / aux1.total)),1) * 100 as percentual
FROM (

    (SELECT 
                round(sum(gin.Caixa_9L /1000),4) AS total
        FROM gin 
        WHERE sales_channel = 'duty paid' 
            or sales_channel = 'travel retail') AS aux1,
    (SELECT 
                round(sum(gin.Caixa_9L /1000),4) AS duty_paid 
     FROM gin 
     WHERE sales_channel = 'duty paid')  AS aux2

)
```